# Sed replace text with another text

Tags: sed

I want to replace the text `disable_functions =` with: `disable_functions = show_source, system, shell_exec, passthru, exec, phpinfo, popen, proc_open, ini_set` in my **php.ini** file with SED.

This is my SH code:

```
sed -i /disable_functions =/disable_functions = show_source, system, shell_exec, passthru, exec, phpinfo, popen, proc_open, ini_set/g' /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

I don't know why it is not working if I execute the .SH script.
Can someone help me with it?

Comment: You might want to worry about what happens if you run this script on a `php.ini` file where it has already got some functions disabled.  It looks like you'd get `ini_set first_previously_disabled_function` with no comma in between.  It'll be up to you to work out whether that matters — for a one-off change, it is a non-issue, but if it will be released to customers, such things can really spoil someone's day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the search `'s` tag in your line, use this:

```
sed -i 's/disable_functions =/disable_functions = show_source, system, shell_exec, passthru, exec, phpinfo, popen, proc_open, ini_set/g' /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```